# SqliteDatabase in Android

Tags: android

how to write

```
select * from customerdetails where locality = " something"
```

in the form of

```
"Select * from customerdetails where locality =?" + locality + ";";
```

in this case `lacality` is *variable*
Anyone can please solve my problem
Thanks in advance

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor c = db.query("customerdetails", null, "locality =?", new String[]{locality}, null, null, null);
```

or you can use raw query like

```
db.rawQuery("Select * from customerdetails where locality = ? ", new String[]{locality});
```